# Dry-Validation - no implicit conversion of Float into String on rules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dry-validation

I'm trying to validate the value of a key into my schema.

But I'm getting a `no implicit conversion of Float into String` because the value is a float and I'm using a regex to validate the format.

```
VALIDATION_PARAMETERS = Dry::Validation.Schema(ApplicationSchema) do
  required(:uid, :string).filled
  required(:value).filled

  rule(insulating_surface: [:uid, :value]) do |uid, value|
    uid.eql?('insulating_surface').then(value.format?(FLOAT_FORMAT))
  end
end
```

I also tried to convert Float into String but it returns `undefined method format?' for #<String:0x0000557d8877a910>`

```
rule(insulating_surface: [:uid, :value]) do |uid, value|
  uid.eql?('insulating_surface').then(value.to_s.format?(FLOAT_FORMAT))
end
```

Comment: Why do you need to validate Float with Regexp? Or let me ask this differently: how could you create a float value in Ruby that does _not_ match the "float pattern"?

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov Sometimes the type of `value` can change with `uid`

If `uid` is 'insulating_surface', then I must check `value` must be a Float.

If `uid` is 'accommodation_type', then I must check `value` is a String with a specific pattern of words

Comment: Got it. But why regexp? Check the class explicitly (better using built-in predicates). See the answer below - maybe it will help

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with dry-validation, but I see a lot of built-in predicates documented, including the `float?` one. Try the following instead:

```
rule(insulating_surface: [:uid, :value]) do |uid, value|
  uid.eql?('insulating_surface') > value.float?
end
```

Comment: Might also consider `decimal?` as rails has a tendency to use `BigDecimal` over `Float` in a lot of cases. but this is the correct way to validate this and I have used `dry-validation` in multiple projects

Comment: @engineersmnky I'm extremely sorry for the late reply.

The reason is that we are validating the user's input. We found a solution by preprocessing the data from the controller before using the validation